# How to insert a <span> tag after a div in YUI only once?

Tags: css, yui

I am trying to insert a  tag after a div via following YUI source:-

```
      Y.one('#solr_ping_status').insert('<img src="pix/success.png">','after');
```

The following statement inserts the tag at every click. But I want it to be inserted only once? How can I restrict in to fire an event only once ? or the existing event should override?

Thanks In advance :)

Comment: inserted only once after click or after dom ready?

Comment: why is this `php` related?

Comment: after a click event ! what i am trying to do in onclick event i trigger a php function that return the server status. until the previous status (that may be failed or okay) removes if the user clicks again the one more ajax image appears that looks wired. the timeout of the previous status message is 2 sec. so what i want is until previous status not disappear there should be no click event or it should replace existing one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use once: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_once

example:

```
YUI().use('event', function (Y) {
    Y.one('#mybtn').once('click', function (e) {
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```